# In Mansfield Park, why did Maria Bertram and Henry Crawford get together?

Tags: jane-austen, mansfield-park

I just finished reading Mansfield Park, and so far after (5 books) it is my favorite. However there are some things which I may unintentionally skip over.

I understand that Maria was a selfish person who thought she herself could do no wrong. However I believe that she must have known that leaving her husband and going with Henry Crawford would be frowned upon. I don't understand why she would do this. I don't think selfish is a good enough reason since she was of high birth and proper education. Is there any other reason that I might miss in the book?

Also the last chapter gives me the impression that Henry was still in love with Fanny (I love her too) even right up to the moment when he went off with Maria. So why did he do it? He knew Maria was married. He knew Fanny's opinion of him was softened, and he still loved her. So I don't understand why he would do something like this?

Comment: Both Maria Bertrum and Henry Crawford are set up as amoral and unlikeable characters. Their actions serve to underpin Fanny's high moral ground and drive much of the plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is at least one part of the question that is wrong - that Maria was of "proper education". This is, in fact, one of the main morals of the story - the education of Maria and Julia was actually seriously mishandled.

While Sir Thomas Bertram has (according to the novel) a sound moral understanding and a willingness to pass this on to his offspring, he is ineffectual in doing so, while having his efforts undermined by Mrs Norris (Mrs Bertrand is so indolent as to not be a significant factor - we are told in Chapter II that she "paid not the smallest attention" to the education of her daughters). Had Sir Thomas taken a evn closer interest in his children, and been a slightly less dreadful character to them, he might have detected that Maria (and, to a lesser degree, Julia) were in fact morally defective: both sisters were perfectly able to show good manners and a presentable front as long as the stakes were low, but when they were put in a situation that required good moral fibre, they failed. This is pretty much all put explicitly forward in Chapter XLVIII.

Maria's actions are actually easy to understand: she is married to a dull but rich man, whom she has nothing very much in common with and whom she does not care for. She is morally very shallow and her reputation is at best a secondary concern. Recall the whole play episode, where being close to Henry Crawford is so important for both her and Julia that they are willing to go to great lengths, even at the risk of making a scandal. Maria might have either not given the consequences of an affair with Henry much thought, or she might have believed that she could easily keep it secret.

As for Henry, well, I do not think the explanation we are given in Chapter XLVIII at all unlikely: essentially they met, Maria was cold and indifferent, and he decided that he wanted to see her foolishly in love with him again. His love for Fanny, we are told, only spurred him on: he wanted to see Maria humiliated in order to elevate Fanny. He might have rationally understood that this was an unwise action, but as he never was trained to restraint, such understanding did him no good.

Ultimately, a lot of energy in the book is spent on presenting the Crawfords as morally corrupt, and Maria as without strong moral backbone. Neither of them are used to considering anything but their own pleasure or the direct risk of getting punished. Without more strict moral training than that, neither can resist the chance for quick gratification.

Comment: I have added a few references to relevant chapters, but while I believe that most of it is well supported, quoting relevant examples on e.g. the relationship between Maria and Mr Rushworth would bog the whole answer down.

Answer (score 0):

Maria was married to a man she "despised." Just think of how miserable being married to someone you despise would be. Henry Crawford was manipulative and said and did things that made Maria think that he must love her, and so she fell in love with him. It wasn't a rational, or probably even a real love, but she fell under his spell (there are allusions in the Sotherton scenes of Henry being like the tempting snake in the Garden of Eden).

It's understandable why Maria would want to leave her miserable marriage, especially since the book says that she hoped Henry would marry her. It would have been several steps down for her, but she would have been married to someone she loved. In modern days, people would probably have more sympathy for her; she was only twenty-one after all.

Henry, for his part, knew that he was making Maria fall under his spell again, but he didn't realize how powerful it was or how long it would last. He told his sister earlier that he wasn't foolish enough to suppose that Maria's feelings were more lasting than other women's -- so he seemed to think that she would get over him pretty quickly and flirting with her wouldn't lead to any trouble.

I completely agree, though, that it didn't make any sense for Henry to run away with Maria, except that it was necessary for Fanny's happy ending. The most maddening thing about the book is that it gives such a detailed description for every other development and then glosses over this incredibly important one in a couple of vague paragraphs. The book says that everything that followed Henry and Maria's return from Richmond was the result of "her imprudence" and that Henry "went off with her at last, because he could not help it" and implies that the "bustle of the intrigue" was exciting for him. However, it's not at all clear what Henry was thinking/feeling. Did he run off with her because he was tempted by her (it's not clear if their sexual affair started before or after they ran away together), or was it because he couldn't bring himself to reject her if they had already started an affair, or was it because she put the scandal in motion by publicly leaving her husband's house so he had to take her somewhere? Maybe it was because breaking up a marriage gave him a thrill. Whatever the reason might be, his running off with Maria definitely was not consistent with the the rest of the book-- for him to do something so totally against his own interest, or for Maria to be the one with power over him-- and the lack of explanation is very unsatisfying. But it also keeps us thinking about the book.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've edited your post to add some paragraph breaks for easier readability.